# Symfony3 - wrong file permissions with LiipImagineBundle

Tags: php, symfony

I detected a strange behaviour in a Symfony3-project. I'm using LiipIMagineBundle (http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/LiipImagineBundle/index.html) to generate thumbnails. The thumbnails (default) are saved in

> web/media/cache/

thats works fine - but: The file-permissions for the generated files/thumbnails are 0600, which leads - in my case - to an error 403. 
I have on the same server (exactly same software including php-version) a Symfony2.8-project - also using the LiipImagineBundle to generate thumbnails - here the permissions are 0666, which works out of the box.
I don't want to use the umask-thing because of the disadvantages. Switching back to Symfony2.8 for that project is not an option :) Any hints how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a [bug in Symfony 3](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/14246) that [was fixed in the meantime](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/17063) and will be part of the yet to publish 3.0.2 release.

So for now you cannot do nothing more than either updating to 3.0.x-dev or fixing the permissions manually after the files have been dumped.

Comment: Thanks! Thought of something like that, but could't find the bug-report.